# Sensors / processing algorithms to emulate a human's sense of smell

Tags: electrical-engineering, sensors

A lot of research has been devoted to creating electrical devices that emulate biological sensors, including:

- Visual:  Cameras, color/light intensity sensors
- Auditory: Microphones, ultrasonic sensors
- Tactile:  Pressure sensors, temperature sensors
- Balance:  Gyroscopes, accelerometers

However, I have yet to find a comprehensive sensor/processing algorithm to detect and interpret odors.  Certainly, there are "olfactory" sensors which are dedicated to a specific purpose, such as carbon monoxide detectors, and other hazardous gas detectors.  But I have yet to find a general purpose sensor/processing algorithm that can readily detect and interpret odors within the range and resolution of a human nose.

Do such sensors/algorithms exist?  If so, what are they and how do they work?  If not, what are the primary obstacles to developing them?

Comment: [Chromato mass spectrometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_chromatography%E2%80%93mass_spectrometry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odor assessment is usually performed by human sensory analysis using [chemosensors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemoreceptor):

> A chemoreceptor, also known as chemosensor, is a sensory receptor that
>   transduces a chemical signal into an action potential.

Recently I have also heard of [a sensor from Honeywell that could potentially be used in smart phones](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Breakthrough-sensor-to-give-our-smartphones-a-sense-of-smell_id48089). These sensors are also called [electronic noses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_nose#Working_principle):

> Bio-electronic noses use olfactory receptors - proteins cloned from
>   biological organisms, e.g. humans, that bind to specific odor
>   molecules. One group has developed a bio-electronic nose that mimics
>   the signaling systems used by the human nose to perceive odors at a
>   very high sensitivity: femtomolar concentrations.
>
> The more commonly used sensors for electronic noses include
>
> - metal–oxide–semiconductor (MOSFET) devices - a transistor used for amplifying or switching electronic signals. This works on the
>     principle that molecules entering the sensor area will be charged
>     either positively or negatively, which should have a direct effect on
>     the electric field inside the MOSFET. Thus, introducing each
>     additional charged particle will directly affect the transistor in a
>     unique way, producing a change in the MOSFET signal that can then be
>     interpreted by pattern recognition computer systems. So essentially
>     each detectable molecule will have its own unique signal for a
>     computer system to interpret.
> - conducting polymers - organic polymers that conduct electricity.
> - polymer composites - similar in use to conducting polymers but formulated of non-conducting polymers with the addition of conducting
>     material such as carbon black.
> - quartz crystal microbalance - a way of measuring mass per unit area by measuring the change in frequency of a quartz crystal resonator.
>     This can be stored in a database and used for future reference.
> - surface acoustic wave (SAW) - a class of microelectromechanical systems (MEMS) which rely on the modulation of surface acoustic waves
>     to sense a physical phenomenon.